# Calling a function on scope with Expression won't return anything

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Given following simple controller:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('store').controller('CartCtrl', ['$scope', 
            function ($scope) {

        $scope.cartSumFunction = function () {
            return 678;
        };

        $scope.cartSum = 678;

    }]);

})();
```

If I try to output cartSumFunction with an expression, it fails (nothing is printed):

```
<div data-ng-controller="CartCtrl">
    <p>{{ cartSum }}</p> <!-- Works! -->
    <p>{{ cartSumFunction }}</p> <!-- Doesn't work, nothing there! -->
</div>
```

Why does the expression calling a function with a return value not work?

Comment: The `cartSumFunction` is a function, so you should use `cartSumFunction()`

Comment: Damn stupid of me... had too much of jsp lately I guess. If you write it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="CartCtrl">
    <p>{{ cartSum }}</p>
    <p>{{ cartSumFunction() }}</p>
</div>
```